# How do I remove the "Unresolved issue" banner from App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, app-store-connect

One of my previous builds had a problem that made it through to the Apple Review, which resulted in a banner at the top of the app saying

> There are one or more issues with the following platform(s):
>
> 1 unresolved iOS issue

[image]

The issue was fixed, a new build was submitted, reviewed, approved and released - yet the banner persists.

How can I make this erroneous and confusing banner go away?

Comment: Having the same issue. I'm hoping I don't have to wait until the build expires before this message is dismissed...

Comment: Any updates guys?

Comment: None... the banner is still there, 4 submitted and approved builds later...

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Clicking through messages doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the "Testflight" tab, under "Builds" click the rejected build(s) and then the "Expire build" button on the top right.

Comment: What about for iOS submissions? They don't have that option. I can only edit and resubmit for review

Comment: The build the banner is complaining about isn't in that list of expired builds for me, I think it was already rejected. But the banner's still there.

Answer (score 0):

the issue you couldn't see the -minus delete build icon. then follow these steps

step 1: click on App review from the left sidebar
step 2: under inprogess you can see the list of builds submitted for review
step 3: now click on the first resolve link...you can see the  -minus delete build icon to delete build. if not possible is there? then go back and try with another one [I mean under inprogess 2nd review]
step 4: do this step until y find the remove option once all is done now you can able to upload a new build.

I'm facing this issue too long then I directly connect apple connet and fix this problem..